# Unacceptable type of value for ordered to-many relationship when writing swift case

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am working on a project that requires me to add a new test case on an existing file structure. Right now I am doing a test case that needs to do api call to get maintenance information.

The maintenance information I am getting back is structured as follows:

```
@objc(MaintenanceData)
class MaintenanceData: WebServiceEntity, Persistable {

static var contentId: ContentId = "maintenance"

@NSManaged var version: String
@NSManaged var maintenance: Bool
@NSManaged var maintenanceDescription: String?
@NSManaged var features: [FeatureMaintenanceData]?

public static func fieldMapping() -> [FieldName: String] {
    return [
        "version": "version",
        "maintenance": "maintenance",
        "maintenanceDescription": "maintenanceDescription",
        "features": "features"
    ]
}
}
```

** For security reasons, I changed some code

Right now I have to mock a fake `MaintenanceData` to test the `features` property, which is an array of `[FeatureMaintenanceData]`

The `FeatureMaintenanceData` is written as follows:

```
@objc(FeatureMaintenanceData)
class FeatureMaintenanceData: WebServiceEntity, Persistable {

static var contentId: ContentId = "featureMaintenance"

@NSManaged var identifier: String
@NSManaged var maintenance: Bool
@NSManaged var maintenanceDescription: String?

public static func fieldMapping() -> [FieldName: String] {
    return [
        "identifier": "identifier",
        "maintenance": "maintenance",
        "maintenanceDescription": "maintenanceDescription"
    ]
}
}
```

Right now I need to mock the data, there is a function in the `MockDataFactory` which returns a `MaintenanceData` object, I need to make use of it and pass it to the function for testing. The function is written as follows:

```
@discardableResult func createAndInsertMaintenance(
    version: String = "",
    maintenance: Bool = false,
    maintenanceDescription: String? = nil,
    features: [FeatureMaintenanceData]? = nil,
) -> MaintenanceData {
    let maintenance = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(
        forEntityName: String(describing: MaintenanceData.self),
        into: managedObjectContext
    ) as! MaintenanceData

    maintenance.version = version
    maintenance.softUpdateMinimalVersion = softUpdateMinimalVersion
    maintenance.maintenance = maintenance
    maintenance.maintenanceDescription = maintenanceDescription
    maintenance.features = features <-----This is where error occurs

    return updateMaintenance
}
```

I created and pass the fake `FeatureMaintenanceData` to the function

```
    let featureMaintenance = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(
        forEntityName: "FeatureMaintenanceData",
        into: managedObjectContext
    ) as! FeatureMaintenanceData

    featureMaintenance.identifier = "Microwave"
    featureMaintenance.maintenance = true
    featureMaintenance.maintenanceDescription = "test"
```

It however returns an error `Unacceptable type of value for ordered to-many relationship: property = "features"; desired type = NSOrderedSet;`

Since I don't know `Obj-c`, could someone explain to me what is the problem and how to solve it? Much thanks!